# Correctly bundle data files into Apache NIFI .nar file

Tags: maven, apache-nifi

I have a number of NIFI processors that get built into a single NAR file. The structure of the project is as defined by `org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype`. Some of these processors rely on data files in the main/resources directory that I need loaded at runtime and not in a database or external source. All works as expected locally and unit tests pass since the resources are on the classpath.

Usually, I'd use the maven-assembly-plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies so that the resources get bundled with my JAT. But I'm not able to get the same result into the final NAR.

What is the correct build configuration I should include in my parent pom.xml (or module pom.xml) to ensure resources get bundled into my final NAR?

Main parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifiprocessors</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>nifi-processors</module>
        <module>nifi-nar</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

nifi-processors.pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifiprocessors</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-processors</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

nifi-nar.pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifiprocessors</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-nar</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <source.skip>true</source.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-processors</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any files that are in src/main/resources end up in the Jar produced by Maven automatically without using any additional plugins. If you had a file src/main/resources/foo.txt and built a jar, foo.txt would be at the root of the jar next to any packages from src/main/java.